# update map[string]int from string value

Tags: go

I am trying to parse a json-like string which looks like this.

`"abc:9, bar:3"`

What I would like to have at the end is a `map[string]int` which looks like this:

`map[string]int{"abc":9, "bar":3}`

I have gotten as far as splitting it into a set of 'pairs', like so:

`["abc:9", "bar:3"]

I am struggling with how to get that structure into the final `map[string]int`. I have tried ranging over the slice, but I am missing how to actually get it into the map.

```golang
        val := "abc:9, bar:3"
        lsd := make(map[string]int)
        c := strings.Split(val, ",")
        for k, v := range c {
            lsd = v[k] // where I am struggling, I know this is wrong, but I can't seem to find the proper syntax and tools for this
        }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to end up with the map[string]int I am looking for here?

Comment: Hi @Jhon, trying to figure out what you need here - is `cfg` another map of string? Are you trying to take a part of the `abc:9, bar:3` and put it into some key of the `lsd` variable? is `abc:9, bar:3` a representation of a `map[string]int` perhaps?

Comment: @Slabgorb , hi, `cfg` is type `cfg := map[string]string{}`

Comment: @Slabgorb - im trying to put inside the `lsd` the value from `"abc:9, bar:3"`

Comment: @Slabgorb - please see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tiny bit cheesy but I was having trouble making fmt.Sscanf grok the pattern, so I am just splitting again. And you may have been missing `strconv` - `strconv.Atoi` is a quick converter.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    lsd := make(map[string]int)
    toParse := "abc:5, foo:5"
    parts := strings.Split(toParse, ", ")
    for _, p := range parts {

        results := strings.SplitN(p, ":", 2)
        val, err := strconv.Atoi(results[1])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)  //probably want to do somethig better
        }
        lsd[results[0]] = val
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", lsd)
}
```

> map[string]int{"abc":5, "foo":5}

https://play.golang.org/p/UadibEzTXWU

Comment: Some gotchas: I am splitting on ", ", if you are not sure whether you will get a space or not, you may need to split on "," then `strings.TrimSpace` before you split on ":".